# Difference between `tf.nn.batch_normalization` and `tf.nn.fused_batch_norm`?

Tags: tensorflow

Their documentation is short and they both refer to the same paper. Is there a difference in what those two functions implement? If no, is one of them soon-to-be obsolete by the other, which one of the two is recommended for use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#use_fused_batch_norm)

> The non-fused batch norm does computations using several individual Ops. Fused batch norm combines the individual operations into a single kernel, which runs faster.

**EDIT: 1/6/2020**

The original link no longer works. This is a [web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180620042504/https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide) provided by [Rika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736559/rika). The updated text says:

> Fused batch norm combines the multiple operations needed to do batch normalization into a single kernel. Batch norm is an expensive process that for some models makes up a large percentage of the operation time. Using fused batch norm can result in a 12%-30% speedup.

Comment: The link doesnt work anymore, can you update how much faster it runs?

Comment: Found it. here is the [performance_guide link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180620042504/https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer with the link you provided.